# How to load model in to controller with geddy

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, geddy

I have a Locations controller and Location model
I want to use the the Location model in another controller but calling

```
geddy.models.Locations.all(...);
```

does not work. It says Locations is undefined.

How do I make it load the model manually? Or should I create a function in the Locations controller to grab the data using a request on the client or a call directly to the controller on the sever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're pluralizing `Locations` when it should be singular: `Location` - hope this helps.